# Markov strong property exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain with *Q* being its transition matrix.

Let $T=\inf\{n \ge 0:X_n \in A\}$ and Let $u(x)=P_x(T<+\infty)$.

**Prove that $u$ verifies the system :**
$$
\begin{cases}{}
u(x)=1 &\text{if } x\in A   \\ 
u(x)=Pu(x) &\text{if } x\notin A
\end{cases}
. 
$$

**My attempt and understanding :**

My understanding is that $T$ represents "the first time we get to the subset $A$" and $u(x)$ represents "the probability of hitting the subset $A$ starting from a $X=x$" ( because $P_x(T=+\infty)$ should represent the probability of never getting in the subset $A$).

That being said, the first part of the system makes sense because if $(X=x) \in A$ then $T=0$ ( smallest $n$ ) and we are already in $A$ so the probability of getting to $A$ should be equal to $1$.

The problem is the second part, **how am I going to use markov strong property to prove that?**

Comment: Have you tried just applying the simple Markov property at time $1$?

Comment: @nejimban what do you mean exactly? Care to elaborate?

Comment: something like $u(x)=P_x(T<\infty)=P_x(1\le T<\infty)=P_x(T\circ\theta<\infty)$ (since $x\notin A$ means $P_x(T=0)=0$)

Comment: I believe you want $P$ to be the transition matrix (not $Q$)?

Comment: I think there is an ambiguity in the question. What is $P$ if it is a constant and what's its relation with $Q$? If $P$ is the same $Q$, then on the equation $u(x)=Pu(x)$, how is it possible to multiply a matrix such as $P$ in a scalar $u(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P=(p_{ij})$ and let $I$ be the state space. Suppose $X_0=i\not\in A$, so $T\geq1$. By the usual Markov property we have $$\mathbb P_i(T<\infty\mid X_1=j)=\mathbb P_j(T<\infty)=u(j).$$
Using the law of total probability, we can condition on the possible values of $X_1$ to get
\begin{align*}
u(i)=\mathbb P_i(T<\infty)=\sum_{j\in I}\mathbb P_i(T<\infty\mid X_1=j)\cdot\mathbb P_i(X_1=j)=\sum_{j\in I}p_{ij}\cdot u(j)=(Pu)(i).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The starting point is that if $x \not \in A$ then $P(T<\infty \mid X_0=x) =\sum_y P(T<\infty \mid X_0=x,X_1=y) P(X_1=y \mid X_0=x)$. This follows from using the total probability formula via conditioning on the outcome of the first step. Then you need to simplify that using the other properties of the situation.